# Reuse the result of a query with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

```
$events='';
$ps = $pdo->prepare('SELECT description FROM events WHERE evdate = "'.$deets.'"');
    $ps->execute();
    $status = (bool) $ps->fetchColumn();
    if($status>0){
            $events .= '<div id="eventControl"><button     onMouseDown="overlay()">Close</button><br /><br /><b>' . $deets .'</b><br /><br /></div>';
               $ps = $pdo->query('SELECT description FROM events WHERE evdate = "'.$deets.'"');
            while($fs=$ps->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
                    $desc = $fs['description'];
                    $events .= '<div id="eventBody">' . $desc .'<br /><hr><br /></div>';
                }
        }
echo $events;
```

Why in this code I had to again call $pdo->query for $fs['description'] to work,why it didn`t let me reuse the $ps from the first query,did execute had something to do with it?Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to reuse? What results you get?

Comment: why are you using string interpolation instead of binding the parameters?

Comment: I`m a beginner,I`m working from a tutorial.

Comment: Loop the results into an array and then use the array throughout the page accordingly.

Comment: Yes,but thats not the question.

Comment: store the results into a variable, bam, you can reuse it now.

Comment: use `$result = $ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);` and use the `$result` array. More information on [PDOStatement::fetchAll here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: Already tried it,same result:does not work.It wants a new query,I have no idea why.

Comment: yes, but with the above statement, you don't have to execute it again. You already have the result. Loop through that using `foreach`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `$ps->fetchColumn()` to tell if the query returned any rows. The problem is that this advances the fetch cursor, so you have to rewind in order for your loop to start again with the first row of the result.

Instead, use `$ps->fetchAll()`, check whether this is non-empty, and then loop over it.

```
$ps = $pdo->prepare('SELECT description FROM events WHERE evdate = "'.$deets.'"');
$ps->execute();
if($rows = $ps->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $events .= '<div id="eventControl"><button     onMouseDown="overlay()">Close</button><br /><br /><b>' . $deets .'</b><br /><br /></div>';
    foreach ($rows as $fs){
        $desc = $fs['description'];
        $events .= '<div class="eventBody">' . $desc .'<br /><hr><br /></div>';
    }
}
```

Another problem in your code was that you were assigning the same `id="eventBody"` for each row returned by the query. IDs have to be unique, so I changed it to a class.

Comment: Speaking of problems, you should also mention that there are potential security holes in building the SQL query without bind parameters and in embedding unescaped content into HTML.

Comment: Thank you,can`t upvote yet because of the reputation requirement.